# Symfony3 with NelmioCors and vue.js with axios - error

Tags: symfony, nginx, vue.js, axios, nelmiocorsbundle

My web server is configured on Nginx. On host srv.local I have Symfony3. Configuration:

config.yml:

```
# NelmioCors Configuration
nelmio_cors:
paths:
    '^/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
```

routing.yml:

```
login_check:
        path: /login_check
        methods: [POST]
```

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            require_previous_session: false
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        anonymous: false
        provider: database
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

On host client.local I have vue.js and method returned response:

```
return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://srv.local/login_check',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  data: {
    _username: 'admin',
    _password: 'admin'
  },
  responseType: 'json'
})
```

After run this vue.js method I get error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I used solution from http://www.jakelitwicki.com/tags/headers/, but then I get "Network error" on response message. I used many solutions from StackOverflow, but without positive result. What I am doing wrong? How could I use NelmioCore and Vue.js (axios) together?

When I have used curl, I got correct json response:

```
curl -X POST http://srv.local/login_check -d _username=admin -d _password=admin
```

Comment: When you tried the http://www.jakelitwicki.com/tags/headers/ solution did you also disable NelmioCorsBundle? I think the http://www.jakelitwicki.com/tags/headers/  solution may not work as expected unless you first remove NelmioCorsBundle. I notice in that posting he says, *“attempted nelmio/cors-bundle with limited success and various odd issues. Particularly the response would come back successful, but the browser would still react as if there was a 404 on the response Header.“*, so maybe it is not worth further time for you try to get NelmioCorsBundle working. His solution there is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I commented Nelmio as @sideshowbarker wrote, my fault. Now I have Symfony error from log:

```
[2017-04-16 12:08:22] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.email AS email_3, t0.password AS password_4, t0.password_expires_at AS password_expires_at_5, t0.status AS status_6, t0.last_login_at AS last_login_at_7, t0.last_wrong_login_at AS last_wrong_login_at_8, t0.last_password_changed_at AS last_password_changed_at_9, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_10, t0.created_at AS created_at_11, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_12 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["NONE_PROVIDED"] []
[2017-04-16 12:08:22] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /srv/srv.local/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): User \"NONE_PROVIDED\" not found. at /srv/srv.local/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php:61)"} []
```

It seems like no username and password is post from vue. 'curl' working still as expected, so I know that credentials are correct. I'm new to vue.js, should I set something for axios other than 'data' property?